# Modern TypeScript won't compile with Webpack when using type: module in package.json and importing .js files

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, nestjs

I have configured my `tsconfig.json` file as follows:

```json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2017",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
        "noEmit": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "allowJs": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "incremental": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./@types"]
    }
}
```

Then, I configured my `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const isCI = require('is-ci');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && !isCI;
const cliApiDomain = isDev ? 'localhost' : 'blavblblblb';
const cliApiUrl = isDev ? `http://${cliApiDomain}:4000` : `https://www.${cliApiDomain}`;
const dashboardUrl = isDev ? 'http://localhost:8080' : 'blalblals';

const configuration = (options) =>
    merge(options, {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                __CLI_API_DOMAIN__: JSON.stringify(cliApiDomain),
                __CLI_API_URL__: JSON.stringify(cliApiUrl),
                __DASHBOARD_URL__: JSON.stringify(dashboardUrl),
            }),
        ],
        experiments: { topLevelAwait: true },
    });

module.exports = configuration;
```

I'm using NestJS, so this Webpack configuration uses Nest's Webpack configuration.

My `nest-cli.json` file:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "webpack": true,
        "webpackConfigPath": "./webpack.config.js",
        "deleteOutDir": true
    }
}
```

And I've also configured `"type": "module"` in my `package.json` file.
However when I compile the code using `nest build`, I get:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts 2:0-44
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.module.js' in '/Users/.../.../cli/src'
resolve './app.module.js' in '/Users/.../.../cli/src'
  using description file: /Users/.../.../cli/package.json (relative path: ./src)
    using description file: /Users/.../.../cli/package.json (relative path: ./src/app.module.js)
      no extension
        /Users/.../.../cli/src/app.module.js doesn't exist
      .tsx
        /Users/.../.../cli/src/app.module.js.tsx doesn't exist
      .ts
        /Users/.../.../cli/src/app.module.js.ts doesn't exist
      .js
        /Users/.../.../.../src/app.module.js.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        /Users/..../.../.../src/app.module.js doesn't exist

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/.pnpm/ts-loader@9.4.2_qqxisngxjbp7lstdk7boexbu3e/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
```

A typical `import` statement in my code:

```
import { CommandFactory } from 'nest-commander';

import { AppModule } from './app.module.js';

await CommandFactory.run(AppModule);
```

As described in TypeScript documentation, although all my files are `.ts` or `.tsx` extensions, I should import from `js?x`: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33588

So anyone could tell how can I fix it?

Comment: [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541) (hint: look at your title)

Comment: Would you please share the `package.json`?

Comment: @MostafaFakhraei

I provided `"type": "module"` in `package.json`. Is there another field you need to know? I cannot find any other related key to this question.